# Python Function giving error "NameError: name 'Marks' is not defined"

Tags: python

Python Function :-

I have data in DataFrame like below (**Dataframe - merged_inner**)

```
RollNo Name Marks
1      ABC  90
2      DEF  91
3      XYZ  92
```

Now i need to find log of Marks

For that i have written a function

```
def transform(data,var):
    data[Var + '_log'] = data.var.apply(np.log)
```

But while running function

```
transform(merged_inner,Marks)
```

Getting below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-b4ba711b77de> in <module>()
----> 1 transform(merged_inner,Marks)

NameError: name 'Marks' is not defined
```

But Marks is there in the DataFrame. I dont know why i am getting this error?

Please suggest

Comment: try `data[var].apply` instead of `data.var.apply` also there is a capitalization error in the function definition, it should be `var` and not `Var` I guess.
And you need to pass `'Marks'` instead of `Marks`

Comment: It might be because of `data.var.apply(np.log)`, use `data[var].apply()` instead.

Comment: Not Working even after ----- def transform(data,var):
    data[var + '_log'] = data[var].apply(np.log)---- Same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Marks' is a string. You have to pass a string:

```
transform(merged_inner, 'Marks')
```

Comment: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'RollNo':[1,2,3],'Name':['ABC','DEF','XYZ'],'Marks':[90,91,92]}
dd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
def transform(data,var):
    data[var + '_log'] = data[var].apply(np.log)
transform(dd,'Marks')
```

​

Answer (score 1):

```
transform(merged_inner,Marks)
```

Above Marks is as a variable, which is undefined. 
Try passing it as a string

Answer (score 0):

```
def transform(data,var):
   df[var + '_log'] = df[var].apply(np.log)

transform(merged_inner,'Marks')
```

There was two mistake first was Marks is an string so it should be inside the quotes and use df[var] instead of df.var